# Laravel - laratrust - how to handle permissions by resource

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

I have a Laravel 5.4 project and I use Laratrust for user roles and permissions. The usage is clear when creating global-scope roles (i.e.: admin), but how should I handle resource based permissions?

Let's say I have multiple budgets. Each user can have as many budgets as they like and they can edit their own budgets. They also can grant access to their budgets for other users.

Shoud I just create individual roles and permissions like:
**budget-123-owner** meaning that the user with this role is the owner of budget ID 123, and **budget-123-read** meaning that user with this permission can view but not edit budget ID 123?
Would this be a good method or should I do it differently? What is the best practice?